# installing apk from a rooted android without user input (grammatically)

Tags: android, root

I came to know from other related questions and their answers that on a rooted android device we can install an apk without user input, in a similar fashion as google play store might be doing.

I have rooted my device and installed my app in the `/system/app` folder. It appears as a system app now. Here is the code I use to install the downloaded apk file

```
private void install(UpdateRequest req, Uri apk) {
    Intent i;
    Log.e("INSTALL PROCESS ", " " + apk.toString());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_REPLACE, true);
    } else {
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    }
    i.setDataAndType(apk, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

The above implementation will show install prompt for user. I want the app to install without user prompt. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this permission to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Then do:

```
 try {   
        String adbCommand = "adb install -r " + fileName;
        String[] commands = new String[]{"su", "-c", adbCommand};
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle Exception
    }
```

Comment: is the `filename` to have the complete path?

Comment: Use file.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: I am having issues. This is the path of downloaded apk `file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/net.kindows.applauncher/files/.CWAC-Update/applauncher-update.apk`  using the above code will ask for SU permission and even on granting permission still It wont install the apk. there is no `exception` as well

Comment: Any warnings or error in logcat (not filtered for app only, everything)?

Comment: I will check it and let you know